# Building referal system by branch.io

Tags: android-studio, branch.io

Can anyone tell me how to make a referal system in my android app from scratch? I m a noobie and a beginner in android dev plz help.

Answer (score 0):

As the first step, you have to integrate the Branch SDK in your app code in order to carry out the following features for the referrals system.
Following that you need to check if you're setting an identity for every user on login/logout and that you've set branch link sharing functionality.

You can navigate to our Referrals page on the Branch dashboard and follow our documentation here : https://docs.branch.io/viral/referrals/

You can set referral rules and the users will be given credits according to the set rules. You can also view the credits received by each user and also provide redeeming credit function for the users.

Please check out out video here for a better understanding :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-qyR6y0wtCM